# Can I use Add-AppxProvisionedPackage to install a denpendency appx pacakge?

Tags: powershell, uwp

I'm trying to use `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage` to install a dependency `appx package` on my `win10` tablet, but failed.

My `win10's` edition is enterprise and the version is 1803.

The script as bellow:

Add`-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath`

`C:\Appx\SMP.UWP_10.7.1.1\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx" -SkipLicense`

The error message like bellow:

> Add-AppxProvisionedPackage : Unspecified error
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath "C:\Appx\SMP.UWP_10.7 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AppxProvisionedPackage], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddAppxProvisionedPackageCommand

Please give me some advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx` is **DependencyPackage**, not the application package.

Try this:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -DependencyPackagePath "all_dependency_package_path" -PackagePath "appxbundle_or_msixbundle_path" -SkipLicense
```

Note:

1. Please fill the above command with a real path. There are usually three dependent packages, separated by ",".
2. After running the command, if there is an error like `A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.`, please install the certificate which in the package folder to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I already fix the issue yesterday. The solution as you said.